# Local string variable not initializing error

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Why are the variable q2,q3 not being initialized, yet q1 is?

This is how the outcome should be similar to:

> WELCOME TO MITCHELL'S TINY ADVENTURE!
>
> You are in a creepy house!  Would you like to go "upstairs" or into
>   the "kitchen"?
>
> > kitchen
>
> There is a long countertop with dirty dishes everywhere.  Off to one
>   side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the
>   "refrigerator" or look in a "cabinet".
>
> > refrigerator
>
> Inside the refrigerator you see food and stuff.  It looks pretty
>   nasty. Would you like to eat some of the food? ("yes" or "no")
>
> > no

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App1 {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String q1;
        String q2;
        String q3;

        String a = "upstairs";
        String b = "kitchen";
        String c = "refrigerator";
        String d = "cabinet";
        String e = "yes";
        String f = "no";
        String g = "hallway";
        String h = "bedroom";
        String i = "bathroom";

        System.out.println("Welcome To Mitchell's Tiny Adventure!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You are in a creepy house, would you like to go upstairs or into the kitchen?");
        System.out.print(">");
        q1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        if (q1.equals(a)) {
            System.out.println("Upstairs you see a hallway.  At the end of the hallway is the master");
            System.out.println("\"bedroom\".  There is also a \"bathroom\" off the hallway.  Where would you like");
            System.out.println("to go?");
            System.out.print(">");
            q2 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

        } else if (q1.equals(b)) {
            System.out.println("There is a long countertop with dirty dishes everywhere. Off to one");
            System.out.println("side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the \"refrigerator\"");
            System.out.println("or look in a \"cabinet\".");
            System.out.print(">");
            q2 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

        }
        if (q2.equals(c)) {
            System.out.println("Inside the refrigerator you see food and stuff.  It looks pretty nasty.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to eat some of the food? (\"yes\" or \"no\")");
            System.out.print(">");
            q3 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        } else if (q2.equals(d)) {
            System.out.println("Inside the cabinet is the boogie man, Are you scare? \"yes or no\"");
            q3 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

        }if (q2.equals(g)){
            System.out.println("You fall in the hallway can you make it? \"yes or no\"");
            q3 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }else if (q2.equals(h)){
            System.out.println("You run into the bedroom were there are monsters live are you afraid \"yes or no\"");
            q3 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }else if(q2.equals(i)){
            System.out.println("You run into the bathroom do you have to use it \"yes or no\"");
            q3 = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }

    }       
}
```

Comment: Tip: instead of having variables like a b c that nobody can possible understand, just name them kitchen, upstairs etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every variable needs to be initialized, before it is accessed the very first time. This can happen automatically for constants and fields, but it needs to be done manually for local variables. So the developers has to decide which value should be the first value for a variable. Mostly it is either `null` (for object types) or `0`/`false` (for primitive types).

So, now about your question:

> Why are the variable q2,q3 not being initialized, yet q1 is?

About `q1`: the first time you try to read the reference "in" that variable is here:

```
if (q1.equals(a)) {
```

but before that, you're having this assignment:

```
q1 = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Here you initialize the variable `q1` with the returned reference of the `keyboard.nextLine()` method call.

Now about `q2`:
(The problem with `q2` and `q3` are the same, so I just focus on `q2`).

You have this assignment in both the `if` and the `else if` block:

```
q2 = keyboard.nextLine();
```

So you try to assign it to another user input if `q1` equals *"upstairs"* or *"kitchen"*. But what will `q2` be, if `q1` is neither of them? Maybe it is *"garden"* or *"downstairs"*, then `q2` will remain uninitialized and the compiler can detect that, hence the error.

You must think about what to do if `q1` is neither of them. You could ask the user again, until you get a valid answer. Or you can exit the program, if such situation is not allowed. It is up to you.

You could also initialize `q2` and `q3` with a certain default value to avoid that error and to avoid unexpected exceptions like a `NullPointerException`. It can be done like this:

```
String q2 = "";
String q3 = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first section, if all your tests for `q1` were false, `q2` would remain uninitialized, but you reference `q2` in the 2nd section; similarly for `q3`.

If a code path exists that allows a local variable to be referenced without first being initialized, this compile error will occur.

Note that the compiler does not examine the *logic* aspects of the code, so for example this will fail to compile:

```
String a = "foo";
String s;
if (a.equals("foo")) {
    s = "bar";
} else if (!a.equals("foo")) {
    s = "baz";
}
System.out.println(s); // error
```

Even though we can see that *logically* `s` must be initialized, the compiler sees only boolean methods, which may result in `s` not being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize local variables before you use them. Try

```
String q1 = "";
String q2 = "";
String q3 = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

well in line 42 :
   `if (q2.equals(c)) {`
and in line 53 :
  `} else if (q2.equals(d)) {` 
you attempt to call the `equals()` method in an uninitialized variable (`String q2`) , try to initialize them first or check them for null values , it depends on how you want to handle each case